# Track Field Values over time

Tags: reporting

Is it possible to track the values of some fields on an object?
What we want to have is some kind of overview where you can see what value a field has in every month of the year

It could look like this:

```
FieldName | Jan | Feb | Mar | ... | Dec
field x   | 1   | 2   | 4   |  1  | 2
...
field y   | 2   | 2   | 1   |  3  | 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of options :

[Field History Tracking](https://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/tracking_field_history.htm)
You can enable Field History Tracking for upto 20 fields on an sObject, and it records every change to the field, which you can report on. Field History data does not count against your total data storage.

[Analytic Snapshots](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/data_about_analytic_snap.htm) 
If you want to take proactive snapshots rather than snapshotting on change, which is what Field History Tracking does, takes a snapshot at a configurable frequency and inserts into an sObject (mapped via config), and you can then report on this to produce the kind of trend report you've shown.

Comment: Yeah I bumped into that already but with Field History Tracking you only see the most recent value, and the value before that (if I'm not mistaken) and not all values it already had before that.

Comment: Field history tracking creates a set of records in an object called ObjectNameHistory or CustomObject__History. It is queryable and contains all changes made to any of the 20 tracked fields. The max tracked fields of 20 can be increased somewhat with good business justification by a call to support, but you should try to work within the limit of possible. Field history tracking is kept in your org for 18 months. 

Also, Chatter Object Feed will track and notify on changed field values, but this data is only kept for 90 days.

Comment: One last thing is that every object with field history turned on should have a standard report type for reporting on field history.

Comment: +1 for Analytic Snapshots, from the question it sounds like exactly the right solution - store the values as they were at each month end.

Comment: I'd also go with Analytic Snapshots in this case, but watch out for storage implications of storing the value each month. Reporting on Field History is impossible if the object is a child in a master-detail relationship.

Comment: I have marked this as the correct answer because either one of the suggestions will serve as a solution to my 'problem'. 

By now I have done some playin' around with the field history reports and have been able to create something close to my needs. I still have some research/testing to do to figure out the Analytic Snapshots :) Thanks!